# Docker not seeing a path

Tags: docker, neo4j

My docker script is this:

```
docker run --interactive --tty --rm \
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \ 
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/backups:/backups \ 
neo4j/neo4j-admin:4.4.9 \
neo4j-admin load --database=neo4j --from=/backups/neo4j.dump
```

When I run it, I'm getting:

> docker: invalid reference format.

> See 'docker run --help'.

> zsh: no such file or directory: --volume=/Users/ironside/neo4j/backups:/backups

> zsh: no such file or directory: neo4j/neo4j-admin:4.4.9

But if I do `cd $HOME/neo4j/backups` and `pwd` I get `/Users/ironside/neo4j/backups`. So it exists. Same with the .dump file. It's there.

The data part works, which is very confusing. I'm trying to follow this part from the docs:
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/maintenance/#docker-neo4j-dump

```
docker run --interactive --tty --rm \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \ 
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/backups:/backups \ 
    neo4j/neo4j-admin:4.4.9 \
neo4j-admin load --database=neo4j --from=/backups/<dump-name>.dump
```

What am I missing here?

I'm using a MAC (MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)) with Apple M1 Pro chip.

Comment: There is a space after the backslash in the `--volume` lines, so rather than escaping the end-of-line the backslash is escaping the space. That means that what looks like a single command line is actually three separate commands. Remove the spaces and things should work as expected.

Comment: I love these... Works, thanks!